# Sonarqube Code Injection (RCE) error for executing code dynamically for eval() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sonarqube

I have used eval() method while writing AngularJS directive for translation. I am getting the error:

> ***Code Injection (RCE)***" in ***SonarQube***.

Same error I am getting for jQuery core library plugin also
Kindly help me to fix this SonarQube issue.

Below is the Sonarqube screenshot

[image]

Below is the code which I used to create a translator method.

```
$scope.$watch('value', function() {

        if ($scope.value) {
            $scope.value=$scope.value.trim();
            if (/^[A-Z0-9|_]*$/.test($scope.value)) {
                var translatedValue = translator[$scope.value];
                element.html(translatedValue);
                return;
            } else {

                var value = eval('(' + $scope.value + ')');

                translateItem(value);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Comment: @novonimo,  I took the screenshot from sonarQube to show the error.
Thank you for informaing me, from next time I will not upload cose as an image.